# Key Value Coding mix up in CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cabasicanimation, key-value-coding

I'm currently trying to create a custom UIControl that has touch-based animations. My issue is that the `transform` and `opacity` *keypaths* are not being seen separate when I come to invoke the `func setValue forKeyPath` method although the layers are being animated are completely different.

To put in simple terms:

1. Upon `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` the (a) `opacity` changes on a layer called `backgroundCircle` and (b) `transform` that applies a `CATransform3DRotate` on `topLayer`.
2. The `CALayer` has an extension that (a) adds the animation via `addAnimation` and (b) and sets the value for keyPath via `setValue` simplifying the code.

The **issue is that the opacity does not animate back to zero, rather incrementally increases until its completely opaque**. However, **when I change the keyPath to anything other than `transform` it works again BUT it does not animate the topLayer**. I'm unsure as to what is exactly wrong here but I suspect it has something to do with the keyPaths.

Here are the methods and extensions:

1. `backgroundCircle` related functions:

   ```
   func animateCircleToTransparent(completion:()->()) {

   let drawAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
   drawAnimation.duration = 0.2
   drawAnimation.repeatCount = 1
   drawAnimation.fromValue = backgroundCircleOpacity
   drawAnimation.toValue = 0
   drawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
   drawAnimation.autoreverses = false
   drawAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.34, 0.01, 0.69, 1.37)
   self.backgroundCircle.ocb_applyAnimation(drawAnimation)

   }

   func animateCircleToOpaque(completion:()->()) {

   let drawAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
   drawAnimation.duration = 0.2
   drawAnimation.repeatCount = 1
   drawAnimation.fromValue = 0
   drawAnimation.toValue = backgroundCircleOpacity
   drawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards
   drawAnimation.autoreverses = false
   drawAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.34, 0.01, 0.69, 1.37)
   self.backgroundCircle.ocb_applyAnimation(drawAnimation)
   }
   ```
2. `topLayer` related functions:

   ```
   func animateTopLineOn() {

   let topTransform = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
   topTransform.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.5, -0.8, 0.5, 1.85)
   topTransform.duration = 0.4
   topTransform.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards

   let translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-4, 0, 0)
   topTransform.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DRotate(translation, -0.7853975, 0, 0, 1))
   topTransform.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.25

   self.topLayer.ocb_applyAnimation(topTransform)
   }


   func animateTopLineOff() {


   let topTransform = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
   topTransform.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.5, -0.8, 0.5, 1.85)
   topTransform.duration = 0.4
   topTransform.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards

   let translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(4, 0, 0)
   topTransform.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DRotate(translation, 0.7853975, 0, 0, 1))
   topTransform.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.25

   self.topLayer.ocb_applyAnimation(topTransform)
   }
   ```
3. 'CALayer' extension:

   ```
   extension CALayer {
   func ocb_applyAnimation(animation: CABasicAnimation) {
   let copy = animation.copy() as! CABasicAnimation

   if copy.fromValue == nil {
       copy.fromValue = self.presentationLayer()!.valueForKeyPath(copy.keyPath!)
   }

   self.addAnimation(copy, forKey: copy.keyPath!)
   self.setValue(copy.toValue, forKeyPath:copy.keyPath!)
   }
   }
   ```